# web3.eth.sendTransaction sends different messages on failure

Tags: transactions, web3js

I am using web3.js to interact with my contract. Now, I am using `eth.sendTransaction`, I am trying to send funds more than sender account posses. But, I am getting different error messages for the different sender and recipient addresses. 
Code I am using:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:to, from: from, value:web3.toWei(amount,"ether")}, function(err1, resp1){  
    if(err1){
        console.log(err1);
    }
    else{
        console.log(resp1);
    }                   
});
```

When I following params for sendTransaction:

```
to: "0x1f76f3dafecf68f316338a169ecd59d695a4b062"
from: "0x62720366ef403c9891e2bfbd5358ee3c8a57b113"
amount: 1099807516000000000000000
password: xxxxxxxx
```

I get error message stating:
 
    `Error: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

And When I change to/ from address as:

```
to: "0x54cfe4ee4ddd537a93ae8f8ff7d4d7f10c70a666"
from: "0x8cc99128e51217f91d5fdfe7182b2b2da218232e"
amount: 1099807516000000000000000
password: xxxxxxxx
```

The error message changes to: 
`Error: Account does not exist or account balance too low`

I am quite amazed since the addresses are absolutely valid. I can see all the address on using `eth.accounts`. Can anyone explain why the error message changes? How can I be sure that the error caused due to low balance?

Comment: Check the account balance using `web3.eth.getBalance()` and compare it to estimated gas * gas price

Comment: Hmm. that's a way, but I was expecting that whenever there is the case, the error message will be  `Error: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value`, soI just read the error message, but this seems to be different with different address, which was unexpected.